# Entity Framework, DateAdd - manipulate dates upon select

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Is it possible to manipulate dates in an EF query while maintaining the flexibility of wildcard select?

In old school SQL you can do this

```
SELECT ID, Name, 
DATEADD (minute, 30, [StartTime]) AS [StartTime]
FROM Titles
```

I know you can to the same in EF with

```
var items = context.Titles.Select(n => new { 
                ID = n.ID,
                Name= n.Name,
                StartTime = System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions.AddMinutes(n.StartTime, 30)
            });
```

The challenge for me is that I'd like to not have to specify all properties.

Is it possible to do something like

```
var items = context.Titles.SomethingSomething(n => 
LinqToUpdateOnly 'StartTime' property);
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a class that holds the original entity plus any additional properties you want and then create a translation method that projects from your entity to the new class. It is not as flexible as you are looking for, but you can do this:

---

Custom class

```
public class TitlePoco
{
  public Title Title { get; set; }
  public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
}
```

---

A single point that handles all the translations you want

```
public IQueryable<TitlePoco> TranslateTitles(IQueryable<Title> query)
{
  return query.Select(n => new TitlePoco { 
                Title = n,
                StartTime = System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions.AddMinutes(n.StartTime, 30)
            });
}
```

---

Then you call your method like this

```
var items = TranslateTitles(context.Titles.Where(x => ...));
```

Comment: Actually, this is what I'm doing :) But it still doesn't answer the question (hopefully I'm asking it right). I specifically do not want to have to '.Select(n => new....)'. The point is that I want the query itself to be flexible. In the event that I add a column (and poco class property) I don't want to have to go through the entire DAL to change the '.Select(n => new' statements.

Comment: @Michael'mital'Pedersen - Can you give an example of why you want to modify the entity property directly, instead of adding a property via a partial class?

Comment: it's all a matter of performance. Let's say "StartTime" is UTC and I want to display 100,000 records with the datetime converted to a different timezone. In this case I want the SQL Server to add 120 minutes (example) to StartTime before returning the results. This should perform much better than calling a property in a partial class 100,000 times.

Comment: @Michael'mital'Pedersen, What about creating a class that contains your entity plus any additional properties, this way you dont have to worry about any properties changing on your entity, but you can still do the calculations on sql server for any additional properties, take a look at the updated answer

Comment: I thought about this too. Only reason I didn't do it already is that it would introduce a second "layer" in the entity as far as DAL goes, which is what I was trying to avoid.
However, for this application performance is more important that maintainability (:-/), so I'll have to set aside my aversion for DAL code logic exceptions and do as you suggest. 
I'm accepting this answer. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about this for old school?

```
var items = context.Titles.ToList();
foreach(var title in items) StartTime = StartTime.AddMinutes(30);
```

Comment: Absolutely not. The 'ToList()' will cause the query to execute and property update to occur afterwards. This type of simple mass-manipulation is best placed on the SQL Server.